# How to insert duplicate entry into SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have searched online and tried the below solution but it does not work; it doesn't enter a row into the table..

```
INSERT INTO [CollisionBegin] 
    SELECT '999-999-99999-9999-9999', [LocalNum], [version], [Submitted] 
    FROM [CollisionBegin] 
    WHERE [UniqueColID] = '2C024576-10BB-4A12-8B6E-BB03191866DE';
```

What I am trying to do: find a row in the table with `UniqueColdID="2C024576-10BB-4A12-8B6E-BB03191866DE"`

This should retrieve ALL of the columns that correspond to a row with this `UniqueColID`. Now I want to reinsert this record BUT with a **NEW** `UniqueColID, "999-999-99999-9999-9999"`.

The above code was a solution I found around the web but it did not work for me because after I execute that statement in my stored procedure, nothing happened.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AmendInsertDuplicateFields] 
AS
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO [MVCNew].[dbo].[CollisionBegin] 
      SELECT
         '999-999-99999-9999-9999', [LocalNum], [version], [Submitted] 
      FROM 
         [MVCNew].[dbo].[CollisionBegin] 
      WHERE 
         [UniqueColID] = '2C024576-10BB-4A12-8B6E-BB03191866DE';
END
```

I know that I have to provide the values explicitly to the insert:

```
INSERT INTO [MVCNew].[dbo].[CollisionBegin] (Column1, Column2, Column3, etc) 
   SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, etc 
   FROM...
```

BUT I have about 8 tables I need to do this for and 30 columns per table so that would be confusing..

I just tried:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE chan2 ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM [MVCNew].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin] WHERE UniqueColID='2C024576-10BB-4A12-8B6E-BB03191866DE'; 
UPDATE chan2 SET UniqueColID='999-999-99999-9999-9999'; 

INSERT INTO [MVCNew].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin] SELECT * FROM chan2; 
DROP TABLE chan2;
```

But I get the error:

```
Unknown object type 'TEMPORARY' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.
```

Comment: Try just the select part of the query. Are there any records in the result?

Comment: Do you get any errors - and if so: what are they? Also: I would **always** specify the **full list of columns** in my `INSERT` statement: `INSERT INTO MVCNew.dbo.CollisionBegin(UniqueColID, LocalNum, Version, Submitted) ......` to avoid any issues with too few or too many columns specified, or specified in the wrong order.

Comment: I dont get any errors. If I DO run the select statement on its own I get:

(No column name)
999-999-99999-9999-9999

and the rest of the fields displayed are from the UniqueColID='2C024576-10BB-4A12-8B6E-BB03191866DE'


The problem is why is it not inserting the uniquecolid of 999....into the uniquecolid? yet it retrieves the rest of the columns from the 2C0...unqiueColID

Comment: @Nadal: could it be that you **already** have an entry with that "999-999-99999-9999-9999" UniqueColId, and the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` is set to silently ignore duplicates?

Comment: Is your [UniqueColID] a primary key or does not allow duplicates?

Comment: Yes - it's boring and mindless work to type all those columns... good tools (like SQL Prompt) help you make this a lot easier. **Not** specifying the column list for your `INSERT` can lead to **extremely** annoying errors that are tremendously hard to find - avoiding such a "bug hunt" just once will be more than worth typing those columns ....

Comment: Just to add to this bog standard SMS allows you to drag and drop the "Columns" folder from the object explorer for each table. This will populate all of the field names for you

Comment: UniqueColID IS primary key so that column cant have duplicates..

Comment: Is UniqueColID an identity field?  If so, you would also get errors trying to insert into that field unless you tell SQL Server to allow you to change it.  I have sometimes seen it ignore the value for that type of field and just generate a new value for it with the rest of the data used for the other fields, bot not sure what makes it do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer on your [your other thread on this same topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10934438/1442492) In short, yes, I would suggest manually listing all the fields, but no, you don't need to type them all yourself.

If you are really motivated to do this without listing all the fields, you'd need to get into some dynamic SQL (or, say, a SQLCLR procedure) to make it happen. It can be done, and it should work, but it's much more complicated for something that really is probably best solved by writing the queries the conventional way.

Comment: Dominic, I dont know if I 100% grasp what you said but is the below code what you mean?

Comment: INSERT INTO [MVCNew].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin] SELECT * FROM [MVCNew].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin];
UPDATE [MVCNew].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin] SET UniqueColID = '999-999-99999-9999-9999' WHERE UniqueColID ='2C024576-10BB-4A12-8B6E-BB03191866DE'; 
INSERT INTO [MVCNew].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin] SELECT * FROM [MVCNew].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin];

Comment: I think what you posted on the other thread would just insert a record it wouldnt necessarily insert a duplicate using WHERE... :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write out how the final query would look in that thread. I've just edited that answer. Is it clearer now?